# how to call Activity asynctask from custom adapter in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, custom-adapter

I have made an activity in that i have a listView and ,I have Implemeted a custom adapter for that ListView ,I have implemeted ListItem's textView's Clickevnet,In That I want to call my activity's AsyncTAk inside that customAdapter,CAn anybuddy tell me how can i do that? my code is as below:
**main.java**

```
package com.epe.yehki.ui;

import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.epe.yehki.adapter.BuyingRequestAdapter;
import com.epe.yehki.backend.BackendAPIService;
import com.epe.yehki.uc.Header;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Const;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Pref;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Utils;
import com.example.yehki.R;

public class BuyingreqActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button viewReq, postReq;
    EditText productName;
    TextView productCategory;
    TextView expTime;
    TextView productDesc;
    TextView estOrderQty;
    ImageView proImg;
    Button send;
    ImageView iv_fav_menu;
    private int flag = 1;
    ScrollView scr_post;
    RelativeLayout scr_view;
    RelativeLayout quote_view;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String viewURL, postURL;
    JSONObject jsonObj;
    JSONArray requestes = null;
    JSONArray quotes = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> reqList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> queList;
    private BuyingRequestAdapter buyingRequestContent;
    RelativeLayout rl_botm;
    ListView lv;
    Header header;
    Calendar dateandtime;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_CAMERA = 100;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 200;
    private Uri picUri;
    int la, lo;
    final int CAMERA_CAPTURE = 1;
    private static String fileName;
    Intent in = null;
    ListView quoteList;

    private String imagePath;
    private Uri imageUri;
    String buyer_request_id, reqID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buying_request);
        InitializeView();
        productCategory.setOnClickListener(this);
        send.setOnClickListener(this);
        expTime.setOnClickListener(this);
        proImg.setOnClickListener(this);

        dateandtime = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
        header.back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                finish();
            }
        });

        reqList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        queList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        viewReq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                flag = 2;
                reqList.clear();
                iv_fav_menu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_two_fav);
                new GetBuyingReqList().execute();
                scr_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                quote_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rl_botm.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                scr_post.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BuyingRequestDetailActivity.class);

                // getting ProductId from the tag...

                reqID = reqList.get(position).get(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID);
                System.out.println(":::::::::::::::;;THE INTENT FOR THE resuest DETIALS ACTIVITY=================" + reqID);
                in.putExtra(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID, reqID);
                startActivity(in);
            }

        });
        postReq.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                flag = 1;
                iv_fav_menu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_one_fav);
                quote_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                scr_post.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                rl_botm.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                scr_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.tv_pro_cat:

            break;
        case R.id.tv_pro_exp_tym:

            DatePickerDailog dp = new DatePickerDailog(BuyingreqActivity.this, dateandtime, new DatePickerDailog.DatePickerListner() {

                @Override
                public void OnDoneButton(Dialog datedialog, Calendar c) {
                    datedialog.dismiss();
                    dateandtime.set(Calendar.YEAR, c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                    dateandtime.set(Calendar.MONTH, c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                    dateandtime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    expTime.setText(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(c.getTime()));
                }

                @Override
                public void OnCancelButton(Dialog datedialog) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    datedialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
            dp.show();

            break;
        case R.id.btn_send:
            new postBuyingReqList().execute();

            break;
        case R.id.iv_img:
            showCustomeAlert2(BuyingreqActivity.this, "Yehki", "From Camera", "From Gallery");

            break;

        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void showCustomeAlert2(Context context, String title, String rightButton, String leftButton) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(BuyingreqActivity.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_alert);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        final ImageView btn_lft = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_left);
        final ImageView btn_rgt = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.iv_right);
        final Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_cancle);

        final TextView btn_left = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnLeft);
        final TextView btn_right = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnRight);

        btn_left.setText(leftButton);
        btn_right.setText(rightButton);
        cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        btn_rgt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("=========== perform click ==============");
                    String mediaStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath();

                    fileName = "user_" + Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_USER_ID, 0) + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Const.DIR_USER + "/" + fileName));

                    System.out.println(" PATH ::: " + imageUri);

                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);

                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                    String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support capturing images!";

                }

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        btn_lft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                // call android default gallery
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                // ******** code for crop image
                intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
                intent.putExtra("aspectX", 0);
                intent.putExtra("aspectY", 0);
                intent.putExtra("outputX", 200);
                intent.putExtra("outputY", 200);

                try {

                    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), PICK_FROM_GALLERY);

                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }

    void InitializeView() {
        iv_fav_menu = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_fav_menu);
        viewReq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_view);
        postReq = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_post);
        scr_post = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scr_post);
        scr_view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.scr_view);
        quote_view = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.quote_view);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.req_list);
        rl_botm = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_botm);
        header = (Header) findViewById(R.id.headerBuying);
        header.title.setText("Post Buying Request");
        proImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img);
        quoteList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.quote_list);
        productName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pro_name);
        productCategory = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_pro_cat);
        expTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_pro_exp_tym);
        productDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_pro_desc);
        estOrderQty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.et_est_qty);
        send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send);

    }

    /*
     * getting buying request list...!!!
     */
    private class GetBuyingReqList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BuyingreqActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);

            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            String query = "?customer_id=" + Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "");
            query = query.replace(" ", "%20");
            viewURL = Const.API_BUYING_REQUEST_LIST + query;
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();

            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::ADDRESS URL:::::::::::::::::" + viewURL);
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(viewURL, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {

                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST)) {
                        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::true::::::::::::::::" + jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_LIST));
                        requestes = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST);

                        if (requestes != null && requestes.length() != 0) {
                            // looping through All Contacts

                            System.out.println(":::::::::::FLAG IN SUB:::::::::::" + flag);
                            for (int i = 0; i < requestes.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = requestes.getJSONObject(i);

                                buyer_request_id = c.getString(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID);
                                System.out.println(":::::::::::::::MY buying request:::::::::::::" + buyer_request_id);
                                String subject = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                                String date_modified = c.getString(Const.TAG_DATE_MODIFIED);
                                String expired_date = c.getString(Const.TAG_EXPIRY_DATE);
                                String quote_count = c.getString(Const.TAG_QUOTE_COUNT);
                                String buying_request_status = c.getString(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_STATUS);

                                HashMap<String, String> request = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                request.put(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID, buyer_request_id);
                                request.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, subject);
                                request.put(Const.TAG_DATE_MODIFIED, date_modified);
                                request.put(Const.TAG_EXPIRY_DATE, expired_date);
                                request.put(Const.TAG_QUOTE_COUNT, quote_count);
                                request.put(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_STATUS, buying_request_status);
                                reqList.add(request);
                                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::Is filled:::::::::::" + reqList.size());

                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::got an error::::::::::::");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * 
             * */

            buyingRequestContent = new BuyingRequestAdapter(BuyingreqActivity.this, reqList);

            lv.setAdapter(buyingRequestContent);

        }

    }

    /*
     * getting qoute List...!!!
     */
    public class GetQuoteList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BuyingreqActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);

            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            String query = "?customer_id=" + Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "") + "&buyer_request_id=" + reqID;
            query = query.replace(" ", "%20");
            viewURL = Const.API_QUOTE_RECIEVED + query;
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();

            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::ADDRESS URL:::::::::::::::::" + viewURL);
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(viewURL, BackendAPIService.GET);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {

                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    if (jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST)) {
                        System.out.println("::::::::::::::::true::::::::::::::::" + jsonObj.has(Const.TAG_ADDRESS_LIST));
                        requestes = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST);

                        if (requestes != null && requestes.length() != 0) {
                            // looping through All Contacts

                            System.out.println(":::::::::::FLAG IN SUB:::::::::::" + flag);
                            for (int i = 0; i < requestes.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject c = requestes.getJSONObject(i);

                                buyer_request_id = c.getString(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID);
                                System.out.println(":::::::::::::::MY buying request:::::::::::::" + buyer_request_id);
                                String product_name = c.getString(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME);
                                String quote_id = c.getString(Const.TAG_QUOTE_ID);
                                String supplier_name = c.getString(Const.TAG_SUPPLIER_NAME);
                                String status = c.getString(Const.TAG_STATUS);

                                HashMap<String, String> quote = new HashMap<String, String>();

                                quote.put(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_ID, buyer_request_id);
                                quote.put(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME, product_name);
                                quote.put(Const.TAG_QUOTE_ID, quote_id);
                                quote.put(Const.TAG_EXPIRY_DATE, supplier_name);
                                quote.put(Const.TAG_QUOTE_COUNT, status);
                                reqList.add(quote);
                                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::Is filled:::::::::::" + reqList.size());

                            }
                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::got an error::::::::::::");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * 
             * */

            buyingRequestContent = new BuyingRequestAdapter(BuyingreqActivity.this, reqList);

            lv.setAdapter(buyingRequestContent);

        }

    }

    /*
     * post Buying Request api()...!!!
     */
    private class postBuyingReqList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Showing progress dialog
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(BuyingreqActivity.this);

            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            postURL = Const.API_BUYING_REQUEST + "?customer_id=" + Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_CUSTOMER_ID, "") + "&product_name=" + productName.getText().toString().trim()
                    + "&category_id=1&expire_time=" + expTime.getText().toString() + "&detail_desc=" + productDesc.getText().toString().trim() + "&esti_ordr_qty="
                    + estOrderQty.getText().toString().trim() + "&esti_ordr_qty_unit=1&filename=abc.jpg&image=abc.png";
            // Creating service handler class instance
            postURL = postURL.replace(" ", "%20");
            BackendAPIService sh = new BackendAPIService();

            System.out.println(":::::::::::::::::::post buying request URL:::::::::::::::::" + postURL);
            // Making a request to url and getting response
            String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(postURL, BackendAPIService.POST);

            Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);
            try {
                if (jsonStr != null) {

                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    if (jsonObj.get("status").equals("success")) {
                        flag = 0;
                    }

                } else {
                    Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("::::::::::::::::::got an error::::::::::::");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            Intent i;
            // Dismiss the progress dialog
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            if (flag == 0) {
                Utils.showCustomeAlertValidation(BuyingreqActivity.this, "Request Posted", "Yehki", "OK");
                clearViews();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(BuyingreqActivity.this, "Buying Request has not been posted", 0).show();
            }
            /**
             * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
             * 
             * */

        }

    }

    void clearViews() {
        productName.setText("");
        productDesc.setText("");
        estOrderQty.setText("");
        expTime.setText("Expiration Time");
        proImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.noimage);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE) { // for camera
            try {
                System.out.println("============= FILENAME :: " + fileName);
                if (new File(Const.DIR_USER + "/" + fileName).exists()) {
                    performCrop();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == 2) { // for crop image
            try {
                if (data != null) {
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");

                    Utils.createDirectoryAndSaveFile(thePic, Const.DIR_USER + "/" + fileName);

                    // pro_pic.setImageBitmap(thePic);
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    Drawable dra = (Drawable) new BitmapDrawable(thePic);
                    proImg.setImageDrawable(dra);
                    proImg.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == PICK_FROM_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (data != null) {
                /*
                 * fileName = Const.DIR_USER + "/" + "user_" +
                 * Pref.getValue(ProfileActivity.this, Const.PREF_USER_ID, 0) +
                 * "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                 */
                fileName = "user_" + Pref.getValue(BuyingreqActivity.this, Const.PREF_USER_ID, 0) + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
                Bitmap photo = extras2.getParcelable("data");

                Utils.createDirectoryAndSaveFile(photo, Const.DIR_USER + "/" + fileName);
                ImageView picView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_img);
                picView.setImageBitmap(photo);

            }

        }
    }

    private void performCrop() {
        try {

            System.out.println("============= AFTER FILENAME :: " + fileName);

            Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Const.DIR_USER + "/" + fileName));
            cropIntent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
            cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 200);// 256
            cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 200);

            cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(cropIntent, 2);
        }

        catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {

            String errorMessage = "Whoops - your device doesn't support the crop action!";
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

}
```

**adapter.java**

```
package com.epe.yehki.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.epe.yehki.ui.BuyingreqActivity;
import com.epe.yehki.ui.BuyingreqActivity.GetQuoteList;
import com.epe.yehki.util.Const;
import com.example.yehki.R;

public class BuyingRequestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> BuyingRequestArray;
    private Context mContext;

    public BuyingRequestAdapter(Context paramContext, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList) {
        this.mContext = paramContext;
        this.BuyingRequestArray = productList;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.BuyingRequestArray.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int paramInt) {
        return Integer.valueOf(paramInt);
    }

    public long getItemId(int paramInt) {
        return paramInt;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public View getView(int paramInt, View paramView, ViewGroup paramViewGroup) {
        LayoutInflater localLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService("layout_inflater");
        Viewholder localViewholder = null;
        if (paramView == null) {
            paramView = localLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_buying_req, paramViewGroup, false);
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();
            localViewholder.sub = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.sub));
            localViewholder.expDate = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.exp_date));
            localViewholder.quote = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.quote));
            localViewholder.status = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.status));
            localViewholder.lastUpdate = ((TextView) paramView.findViewById(R.id.last_updated));

            paramView.setTag(localViewholder);

        } else {
            localViewholder = new Viewholder();
            localViewholder = (Viewholder) paramView.getTag();
        }

        System.out.println(":::::::::::::::values:::::::::::::::" + BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME));
        localViewholder.sub.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_PRODUCT_NAME));
        localViewholder.expDate.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_EXPIRY_DATE));
        localViewholder.lastUpdate.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_DATE_MODIFIED));
        localViewholder.quote.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_QUOTE_COUNT));
        localViewholder.quote.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0000ff"));
        localViewholder.status.setText(BuyingRequestArray.get(paramInt).get(Const.TAG_BUYING_REQUEST_STATUS));

        localViewholder.quote.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /*
                 * HERE I WANT TO CALL "GETqUOTElIST" ASYNCTASK OF MY ACTIVITY/////!!!!!!!
                 */
            }
        });
        return paramView;

    }

    static class Viewholder {
        TextView sub;
        TextView lastUpdate;
        TextView expDate;
        TextView quote;
        TextView status;

    }
}
```

Comment: put asyntask in your adapter.

Comment: so how to bind activity's ListView from adapter? ????

Comment: @kyogs-can you tell me how to make visible or invisible a relativeLayout of an activity from customAdapter class?

Comment: you need to pass relative layout object in your adapter constructor.

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the correct approach of coding ,where in you have all the asyncs in one activity.

But to achieve what you want you can use the context that you pass in the adapter like this:

```
((YourActivityYouArePassing)mContext).someMethod();
```

the activity's context must be the same as the one you are using for type casting, and `someMethod()` should be a method declared inside the activity with public keyword.

in `someMethod()` you could then call your async task like:

```
public void someMethod() {
     new AsyncClass().execute();
}
```

**EDIT:**

The onClick will look like this in the adapter

```
localViewholder.quote.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            /*
             * HERE I WANT TO CALL "GETqUOTElIST" ASYNCTASK OF MY ACTIVITY/////!!!!!!!
             */
             ((YourActivityYouArePassing)mContext).someMethod();
        }
    });
```

Hope that helps!!

Comment: I tried your code but getting this error `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.package.Activity`

Comment: tht is because you would have been passing an application context, instead of the activity context

Answer (score 0):

You can call async task on text click inside Custom adapter

```
localViewholder.quote.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               new GetBuyingReqList.execute();
            }
        });
```

and make GetBuyingReqList class private to public

Answer (score 0):

put below code where u want

```
GetBuyingReqList getBuyingReqList = new GetBuyingReqList ();
getBuyingReqList .execute();
```

Answer (score -1):

Possible duplicate [How to Call AsyncTask from Adapter class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068907/how-to-call-asynctask-from-adapter-class)

found these answers

1. move your adapter class inside your activity class and make adapter class as inner class.so you have access for calling Asynctask in adapter
2. Remove AsyncTask Inner class from activity class and Make AsyncTask as a separate class (put it in your package). After that you can call like this "new Asynctask().execute();" from any where
3. what i did... i sent an instance of the activity to the adapter while initializing, then i called a method at the activity by activity.method() and this method calls the AsyncTask